# How to restart operation from the point it was interrupted?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, logic

I am working on big database and one table contain hundreds of thousands of entries. If I am trying to retrieve data and if because of some interruption, process stops after retrieving thousand rows of table.

How can I restart my operation from the point where it was interrupted?

How can I know the point of interruption?

Comment: try for `transactions`. `Commit... rollback ...savepoint` I think you are looking for `savepoint`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande, OP is talking about data fetch, not DML.

Comment: I dont think so you can start select statement in between if its interrupted.. Using rownum or rank etc funtions you divide your select statement into multiple statements and then start where it was interrupted.. but again everything depends upon what requirement is... where you are storing data... etc

Comment: Look into Commit and Savepoint: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/transact.htm#CNCPT016